# Expressing a function in terms of its derivatives.

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a real-valued function $f(x)$, and let $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ be its first and second derivatives respectively. How would I go about expressing $f(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ Detailed explanation would be appreciated very much.

P.S. It's not a homework question, the question came to my mind randomly (I'm a curious high school student with little to no background in calculus).

Comment: Hint: look for Taylor's Formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $g(x)$  and/or $h(x)$ are given as functions of $x$ then $f$ can be found by simple integration, see other answers.

Sometimes we only are given a relation between the values of $g$ ($=f'$) and $h$ ($=f''$), as in the following example: A polystyrene ball is dropped from a cliff. Assuming that air resistance increases quadratically with the velocity its height $t\mapsto y(t)$ then satisfies the differential equation
$$\ddot y(t)=-g +\mu \bigr(\dot y(t)\bigr)^2\qquad(t\geq0)\ .$$

So assume that we are confronted with a constituent equation
$$\ddot y= p(\dot y)\ ,$$
where  the given function $p(\cdot)$ connecting he values of $\dot y$ and $\ddot y$ is continuous and nonzero. Furthermore assume initial values $t_0=0$, $y(0)=y_0$, and $\dot y(0)=v_0$ as given. Introducing $v(t):=\dot y(t)$ as a new unknown function we have
$$\dot v=p(v),\quad{\rm resp.}\quad{dv\over dt}=p(v)\ .$$
Separation of variables gives
$$\int_{v(0)}^{v(t)}{dv\over p(v)}=t-0\ .\tag{1}$$
Assume that $H(\cdot)$ is a primitive of ${1\over p(\cdot)}$. Then $(1)$ can be written as
$$H\bigl(v(t)\bigr)-H\bigl(v_0)\bigr)=t\ .\tag{2}$$
Since $H(\cdot)$ is monotone by assumption on $p(\cdot)$ we can rewrite $(2)$ as
$$v(t)=H^{-1}\bigl(H(v_0)+t)\bigr)\ ,$$
and this finally leads to
$$y(t)=y_0+\int_0^tH^{-1}\bigl(H(v_0)+t')\bigr)\ dt'\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Without notice for details:

Function $f$ can be approximated by means of its derivative $f'$.

This by: $$f\left(x\right)\sim f\left(a\right)+f'\left(a\right)\left(x-a\right)$$
where $a$ can be chosen.

The right side is a linear approximation.

This can be proceeded. There is a quadratic appoximation: $$f\left(x\right)\sim f\left(a\right)+f'\left(a\right)\left(x-a\right)+\frac{1}{2}f''\left(a\right)\left(x-a\right)^{2}$$
making use of $f'$ and $f''$. Going on like this you end up with
a Taylor series: $$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{\left(n\right)}\left(a\right)}{n!}\left(x-a\right)^{n}$$

Comment: This assumes we already know the function value $f(a)$.

Comment: @naslundx If you try to approximate by derivatives without that sort of knowledge then for $f$ and $f+c$ you will get the same result, since the constant will not be there in the derivatives. So this knowledge cannot be missed if you want to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $g=f'$, then you know that $f$ is the antiderivative of $g$, that is $$f=\int g(x) dx.$$

More specifically, $f$ is *one of* the antiderivatives. Since you can change $f$ to $f+C$ for any constant $C\in\mathbb R$, you don't know $f$ exactly, but up to this constant.